# Implementing base members of a derived interface

Tags: .net, vb.net, interface, coding-style

Let's say I have the following interfaces:

```
Public Interface IFooBase
    Sub Bar()
End Interface

Public Interface IFoo
    Inherits IFooBase

    Sub Zim()
End Interface
```

I understand that a class which implements `IFoo` implicitly implements `IFooBase`, and that all IFooBase members can be specified via the derived interface (e.g. `Public Sub Bar() Implements IFoo.Bar`) without issue, and no error is given if a class specifies that it implements both the base interface and the derived interface.

So what is the best practice here? My gut feeling is that the class should be implemented as follows:

```
Public Class FooClass
    Implements IFooBase, IFoo

    Public Sub Bar() Implements IFooBase.Bar
    End Sub

    Public Sub Zim() Implements IFoo.Zim
    End Sub
End Class
```

My reasoning is that by explicitly specifying the base interface and declaring the class members at the level they were defined at, the code is more clear and if the derived interface were ever to be refactored, removed, or replaced, the amount of refactoring that needs to be done is strictly limited. But am I missing anything with this approach?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code implementation and would be better served on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: This question is about the behavior of VB.Net interfaces, inheritance, and their implementation in classes. CodeReview is quite clearly a site for reviewing real code in real projects. I see nothing in http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic that would suggest I am off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By implementing both `IFooBase` and `IFoo`, you would be implicitly stating to anyone (else) reviewing the code that `IFoo` does not inherit from `IFooBase`, though implementing both even though `IFoo` inherits from `IFooBase` is not incorrect.

However, should `IFoo` be changed to also inherit from another interface, `IBar` (Interfaces can have multiple inheritances, but not classes), you would be implicitly requiring `FooClass` to also implement `IBar`, even though `FooClass` should not require the additional `Implements IBar`.

Also, if you alter the base interface, you're complicating things more if your implementing classes explicitly implement it than if they implicitly implement it.

I believe that there's something to be said for only implementing the most-derived interface, and not also all the parent interfaces.